# iOS: forcing server to provide updated data

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, web

I'm working on an iPad app that requests data from a server, changes and submits it, and then re-requests the data from the server, displaying it to the user. The app updates the data just fine (the equivalent web app sees the update happening), but the data that the iPad app gets back is the old data. I thought maybe it was the caching flag on the NSURLRequest, but it doesn't look like it.

Here is my sequence of calls:

```
NSString* currentStuff = self.fCurrentIndex.currentStuff;
NSError* err = nil;
[self.fCurrentIndex approve:currentStuff withUsername:username andPassword:password error:&err];

if (err == nil)
{
    // rebuild the case list (grab the data from the URL again first)
    [self getCaseListViaURL]; // grab the updated data
    [self setupUIPanel]; // display it
}
```

Here's the code that grabs the data (the 'getCaseListViaURL' call):

```
NSURLResponse* response;
NSError* err = nil;
NSMutableDictionary * jsonObject = nil;
NSString * urlRequestString;

urlRequestString = [method to get the URL string];

NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlRequestString];
NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                      timeoutInterval:60];

NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                      returningResponse:&response
                                                  error:&err];

if (err == nil)
{
    jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                   error:&err];
}

if (err && error) {
    *error = err;
}

return jsonObject;
```

Is there any way to force the server to serve up the updated data?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Per comments, I'm adding the sequence of update to the server and subsequent pull:

This does the push to the server:

```
NSString* currentStuff = self.fCurrentIndex.currentStuff;
NSError* err = nil;
[self.fCurrentPatient approveStuff:currentStuff withUsername:username andPassword:password error:&err];
```

Where 'approveStuff' eventually calls:

```
__block NSData * jsonData;
__autoreleasing NSError * localError = nil;

if (!error) {
    error = &localError;
}

// Serialize the dictionary into JSON
jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:data
                                           options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                             error:error];
if (*error) return nil;

NSURLResponse* response;
NSString * urlRequestString;

urlRequestString = [self urlStringForRelativeURL:relativeURL
                                 withQueryParams:params];

NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlRequestString];
NSMutableURLRequest * request;
request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                  cachePolicy:self.cachePolicy
                              timeoutInterval:self.timeOutInterval];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
[request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

jsonData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                 returningResponse:&response
                                             error:&localError];
NSMutableDictionary * jsonObject;

if (localError == nil)
{
    jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                                 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                   error:&localError];
}

if (error && localError) {
    *error = localError;
}

return jsonObject;
```

Right after this, I call the aforementioned get call and rebuild the UI. Now, if I stick a breakpoint when I do the get, and check on the web server if the data is updated after the push, I see the data is there. However, when I let the get operation continue, it gives me the old data.

Comment: You've shown us only half of this equation.  Where does this code exist relative to the code that updates the remote data?  Are you certain the remote data is actually updated before the app is actually requesting it?

Comment: post the remaning code ,commenting the cofidential stuff if you have

Comment: @nhgrif, I am sure the code for updating works because if I do the update, and nothing else, another app that accesses the same data shows the update.

Comment: I'm not questioning whether or not the data is eventually updated.  I'm questioning the speed at which it's updated versus the speed at which you're accessing it here.

Comment: Updated the question, please let me know if any other clarifications are needed.

Comment: [method to get the URL string] - if there is parameter like lastUpdateTime, what time do you send? Maybe you are sending your local lastUpdateTime?

Comment: I tried adding a "?timestamp" parameter to the request, but saw no change in behaviour. It's possible I'm doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like the issue was on the server. There were some data structures on the server side that weren't being refreshed when the data was being posted.